# Show notify to user after action

Tags: php, laravel

The Laravel site has a game for users. And i need to do that if the user loses the game, he is shown a notification that cashback has been credited to his balance. But the code doesn't want to work. This is all I am trying to do in the controller.

My code:

```
public function crashBets()
{
    $game = $this->getGameInController();

    $betsLose = Bet::query()->with('user')->where([
        ['game_id', $game->id],
        ['is_win', 0]
    ]);
    # Add cashback
    $betsLose->get()->each(function($bet) {
        # Add cashback
        $bet->user->increment(
            'cashback', ($bet->bank / 100 ) * 1
        );
        $this->cashbackNotify();
    });
    # Update bets
    $betsLose->update([
        'is_win' => 2,
        'multiplier' => $game->multiplier
    ]);

    $bets = $this->getBets();
    return $bets;
}
```

`$betsLose` success update infromation in database. I try add the function:

```
public function cashbackNotify()
{
    return [
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'item_not_found'
    ];
}
```

And call it's function in `$betsLose->get()->each(function($bet) {`, i write `$this->cashbackNotify();` but nothing happens. What i did wrong? How i can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You only return array in `cashbackNotify` function. You must process this data for users. And you must decide how do you move data for frontend.

I think you should check Laravel Notification system on [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications).